# EntityFramework core link tables (view) and navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've got a parent-child relation that I unroll in a a view to give all of the descendants of an entity.

I now want to put a navigation property on an entity that is a list of all its descendants.

```
CREATE TABLE Thing (
   ThingId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   ParentId int NULL
)

CREATE VIEW ThingDescendantOrSelf
AS
  ;WITH cteThing AS (
    SELECT ThingId, ThingId AS DescendantId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.ThingId, t.ThingId
    FROM cteThing cte
      INNER JOIN Thing t ON t.ParentId = cte.DescendantId
  )
  SELECT ThingId, DescendantId
  FROM cteThing
```

Which I want mapped to

```
public class Thing {
  public int ThingId {get; set;}
  public int? ParentId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Thing> DescendantOrSelf {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: if this is ef core, don't you need a join table as this looks like a many to many relationship?

Comment: Thing to descendant-or-self is one-to-many which the recursive query in the view produces from the parent-child relationship in the table.